# updating tables while preserving business rules

Tags: sql

i have the following scenario , business rules and database schema , i want to update customer and salesrep tables by using just SQL while preserving business rules.how can i do that.

scenario:

suppose Premier Products wants to give all their customer and sales
reps a Christmas bonus. All customers will have their balance owing reduced
by $100, and their amount on order increased by $50. The increased amount
on order flows on to their sales reps. But because of the limitation that a sales rep amount on order cannot exceed $1000 (BR4),
 some sales reps will not get a bonus.

(a) how this can be achieved in pure SQL, while preserving all business rules.

BR1. The total amount owed by a customer cannot exceed their credit limit.

BR2. The sales rep's amount on order is incremented by the same amount as their customers.

BR3. All new customers are given a $100 credit, that is an initial balance of -$100.

BR4. A sales rep is not entitled to any commission on sales beyond $1000 on order.

```
/*-- SLSREP Table */
CREATE TABLE SLSREP
(SLSRNUMB DECIMAL(2),
TOTCOMM DECIMAL(7,2),
COMMRATE DECIMAL(3,2) CONSTRAINT CK_commrate CHECK( commrate BETWEEN 0 AND 1),
AMOUNTONORDER DECIMAL(9,2),
CONSTRAINT PK_SLSREP PRIMARY KEY (SLSRNUMB));

/*-- Customer Table */
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(CUSTNUMB DECIMAL(3),
BALANCE DECIMAL(7,2) ,
CREDLIM DECIMAL(5) CONSTRAINT NN_credlim NOT NULL ,
SLSRNUMB DECIMAL(2) ,
AMOUNTONORDER DECIMAL(9,2) ,
CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMER PRIMARY KEY (CUSTNUMB),
CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER_slsrnumb FOREIGN KEY (SLSRNUMB) REFERENCES SLSREP,
CONSTRAINT CK_credit CHECK (balance +  AMOUNTONORDER <= credlim));
```

Answer (score 1):

These requirements seem to be in conflict.

1. Premier Products wants to give all
   their customer and sales reps a
   Christmas bonus.
2. But because of the limitation that a
   sales rep amount on order cannot
   exceed $1000 (BR4), some sales reps 
   will not get a bonus.
3. BR4. A sales rep is not entitled to
   any commission on sales beyond $1000
   on order.

I would model a bonus as a bonus, not as a commission on sales. A bonus isn't a commission or an order; they're all different things. So I propose two new business rules.

**BR5. A bonus is not a commission.**

**BR6. A bonus is not an order.**

Here's one way to implement a table of sales rep bonuses.

```
CREATE TABLE SLSREPBONUS (
   SLSRNUMB DECIMAL(2) REFERENCES SLSREP (SLSRNUMB),
   BONUSDT DATE,
   BONUSAMT DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL CHECK (BONUSAMT BETWEEN 1 AND 1000),
   CONSTRAINT PK_SLSREP PRIMARY KEY (SLSRNUMB, BONUSDT)
);
```

Your customer table has only aggregate amounts, so I'd assume that you'd have to issue a credit in some other part of your accounting system. I'd hope that if you did that, the customers aggregates would be updated properly. (But I have to say I've learned that hope doesn't scale well.)

Comment: @jam: To take care of sales reps, I'd create a table of sales rep bonuses. If you can always apply a credit to a customer, I might issue a $100 credit to the customer. A credit to a customer shouldn't have any effect on commissions to sales reps, and it shouldn't have any effect on the amount on order. (I think. I'm not very good at that accounting stuff.)